# How to run SheepIt Render Farm on macOS Monterey (Blender 3.0)?

Tags: osx, sheepit

I decided to give SheepIt Render Farm a try after not using it for a good number of years. I remember that I used to be able to run it in macOS Terminal to earn points while my machine wasn't busy. But now I can't find much info on how to do that. To make matters worse, I can't even run SheepIt Client (sheepit-client-6.22006.0.jar)

I have no idea which version of Java SheepIt wants, so I followed the [download link](https://java.com/en/download/) on java.com ...this gave me Java Version 8 (although it looks like Java is [actually up to Ver. 21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) - what?!)

So the .jar file won't launch. *When* it shows an error, it is as follows:

[image]

(Other times it fails without providing any feedback.)

I finally found out [how to check Java's console](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/252425/123184) (in Terminal: `java -jar path/to/file.jar`), and I was able to get details about the error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sheepit/client/standalone/Worker has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:601)
```

I am now uninstalling Java 8 and will try to install Java 11.

The [SheepIt FAQ](https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/faq) has been utterly useless, and the [Forum](https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/forum/) seems dead. It would have been nice to have an explanation of which Java version is required, and where to download it.

I should also mention that I want to be able to run SheepIt both from Blender and also headlessly through Terminal.

<sub>Versions: macOS Monterey, Blender 3.0, Java 8(?... it reads `java version 1.8.0_321` even though I used the 8 installer, so maybe Java doesn't count the `1.`... just to add to the confusion)</sub>

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What goes wrong when you download the client from the download page?

Comment: @MrBill Thanks for asking. I can download it, but when I try to run it I get *"Java Application launch failed."* I added a screenshot and some more details in my question.

Comment: Okay... it appears I have solved this. I will post an answer to spare others all of the time I just had to waste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a guide that if I had found earlier, would have made this process a lot easier: [Installing Java 11 on MacOS with HomeBrew](https://medium.com/w-logs/installing-java-11-on-macos-with-homebrew-7f73c1e9fadf)

<sup>Note: it applies to versions higher than 11 too.</sup>

**But wait!** You first need to install Homebrew if you don't have it installed already. And apparently it's easy to screw this up in macOS Monterey, so follow the steps outlined here: [How to setup Homebrew (brew install) on macOS 12 Monterey](https://tech-cookbook.com/2021/10/25/how-to-setup-homebrew-brew-install-on-macos-12-monterey/)

<sup>(In case the link above ever rots, the main thing to know is this command: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`)</sup>

If you've already got Homebrew installed and working, just type `brew update`.

Also, you should uninstall any previous versions of Java before installing a new one (unless you intend to keep multiple versions and [switch between them](https://medium.com/w-logs/installing-java-11-on-macos-with-homebrew-7f73c1e9fadf#8e2e)).

If you find yourself in the same situation as me, it is likely that `brew tap homebrew/cask-versions` seemed to work, but then when you tried `brew cask install java` you were faced with `Error: Unknown command: cask`

Luckily, I found an article about [How to fix Error: Unknown command: cask on macOS Monterey](https://medium.com/@kamara.io/how-to-fix-error-unknown-command-cask-on-macos-monterey-a4e82b9486ee#e957)

It explains that we can just omit `cask` now, because of... reasons.

So instead, type: `brew install java` for the most recent version. Or replace `java` with `java11` if you specifically want version 11, etc.

There is a possibility that even after installing Java, you may test the installation by opening a new Terminal window and typing `java -version`, only to find that it seems Java is still not installed.

But you may have noticed this little message during the installation:

If you need to have openjdk first in your PATH, run:
`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

So type that into Terminal and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>.

After that, typing `java -version` should give you something like this:

```
openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17.0.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 17.0.1+1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Yaaaay!

Now, to run the SheepIt Client, you should be able to type something like: `java -jar  /Users/homefolder/Downloads/sheepit-client-6.22006.0.jar` to run it. Of course check the file path where you have it located, as your path will be unique to you.

[image]

### Updating

SheepIt will periodically prompt you to "update" the client. This term is a bit misleading, as the process does not involve running an update on an existing installation, but simply [downloading](https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/getstarted) the most recent version of the client and then ensuring the file path you use to run it points to the new version. SheepIt will remember your previous settings (dark theme, memory to allocate, etc).